# Issue when Exporting Products Catalog

Tags: magento-1.8, product, catalog, import, export

Could you please help me posting the following issue I have in Magento Community Edition 1.8.1:

"I have issues when exporting the Product Catalog in Community Edition 1.8.1, I have 100,000 items, and the error I get is this:

```
2014-10-08T18:00:09+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined offset: 103041  in app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 875$
Stack trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php(875): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/var/inetpub-lo...', 875, Ar$
#1 app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export.php(150): Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product->export()
#2 app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ExportController.php(86): Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export->export()
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController->exportAction()
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('export')
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_$
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

Does anybody have a clue about this?

Comment: Hi Cinthya and welcome to MageOverflow. If you have two questions - and it seems like it, please post two questions.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen similar behavior coming from M2EPro imported listings.  What it seems to do it drop the shipping field data.  So I just sorted the grid by weight, found any empties and corrected the shipping weight.  The error I got  was:

Notice: Undefined offset: 3347  in /home/builders/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 875

Note the offset is actually the products internal magento ID, so your offset of 103041 is the products ID, edit and resave that item in the backend and try to export again... The export should continue to the next record.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to fix this. But the error which is raised here:

```
if ($defaultStoreId != $storeId) {
    $dataRow[self::COL_SKU]      = null;
    $dataRow[self::COL_ATTR_SET] = null;
    $dataRow[self::COL_TYPE]     = null;
} else {
    $dataRow[self::COL_STORE] = null;
    $dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId]; // THIS LINE
}
```

tries to access an array key which encodes a product id in an array which should contain stock informations, but obviously doesn't.

The array is built here:

```
\Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product::_prepareCatalogInventory
protected function _prepareCatalogInventory(array $productIds)
{
    if (empty($productIds)) {
        return array();
    }
    $select = $this->_connection->select()
        ->from(Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getMainTable())
        ->where('product_id IN (?)', $productIds);

    $stmt = $this->_connection->query($select);
    $stockItemRows = array();
    while ($stockItemRow = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $productId = $stockItemRow['product_id'];
        unset(
            $stockItemRow['item_id'], $stockItemRow['product_id'], $stockItemRow['low_stock_date'],
            $stockItemRow['stock_id'], $stockItemRow['stock_status_changed_automatically']
        );
        $stockItemRows[$productId] = $stockItemRow;
    }
    return $stockItemRows;
}
```

All stock informations from database are read and written in this array. So maybe your product with id `103041` just doesn't have a stock item. You can check easily in `catalog_inventory_stock_item` table.